# Print out contents of two .bib files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, subdividing

I have two .bib file with a selection of references in each.

I would like to print out these references in the same document with diffeent section headings with the numbering of references in each section starting from 1. My first attempt is below: This gives the correct section headings but puts TEST1.bib references in both with no TEST2.bib references...Where am I going wrong? I am using TexMaker to compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multibib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\begingroup
\section*{Section 1}
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{TEST1}
\endgroup
\begingroup
\section*{Section 2}
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{TEST2}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how it is done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{journal,conference}{{Section--1},{Section--2}}

\begin{document}
\nocitejournal{*}
\bibliographystylejournal{plain}
\bibliographyjournal{xampl}        %% use TEST1 here
%    
\nociteconference{*}
\bibliographystyleconference{plain}
\bibliographyconference{doi}       %% use TEST2 here
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

To process this, the commands should be executed as below:

```
pdflatex myfile   %% assuming that the above code is saved as myfile.tex
bibtex journal
bibtex conference
pdflatex myfile
pdflatex myfile
```

Some editors have algorithms (like winedt) which do all these by themselves. If not the above commands should be executed from the same folder as the `myfile.tex` file.

Comment: When running bibtex i get an error saying there is no \bibstyle command found in the .aux file? and no \citation commands and I still only get Test1 references?

Comment: @user2772383 you have to execute `bibtex` on `journal.aux` and `conference.aux`.

Answer (score 3):

That's actually a very simple thing to accomplish, `biblatex` provides support for that out-of-the-box using the `\refsection` environment.

```
\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\section{Section One}
\begin{refsection} % open refsection environment 

    Some Text here \cite{Author1999}

    % This here prints your bibliography
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\section{Next Section}
% repeat
```

If you need more details, check out the [bibtex documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), it even provides examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `bibunits` package to add multiple bibliographies.

```
\usepackage{bibunits}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibunit}[plain]
Some Content here!
\putbib[mybib]
\end{bibunit}

\begin{bibunit}[plain]
Some Content here!
\putbib[mybib]
\end{bibunit}
```

However, you will need to run `bibtex` with different arguments to process new bibliography files `bu1.aux`, `bu2.aux`, etc.